# Which enemies are not consumed by the protozoid slimes, given the chance, in Duke Nukem 3D

Tags: duke-nukem-3d

The slimes that slither out of the eggs in Duke Nukem 3D do not play nice with the other enemies. Despite there often being guards around egg clusters, if the eggs hatches and you leave the area and let them have some time with each other, only the slimes will remain after a short time. This behavior is one tactic to ensure enemies do no return in the highest difficulty setting of the game. However, it appears that not every enemy is susceptible to spontaneous liquidation. Octabrains seems to avoid this grizzly fate but who else?

Which enemies cannot be eaten by slimes?

Comment: Thanks for indirectly letting me know this was even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Duke Nukem Wiki](http://dukenukem.wikia.com/wiki/Protozoid_Slimer)

> The Protozoid Slimer will attack any weaker being close to it. That is, **it will attack and "consume" Assault Troopers, Assault Captains, Pig Cops, Assault Enforcers and Protector Drones. It will do nothing to any other enemy,** and it will not purposely go for any of those enemies (it will only try to attack the player).